# How to send javascript object to node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Let me preface this by saying I'm sure it's something amazingly simple and stupid that I'm missing but I've been trying to solve this for over a week now and it's breaking my brain. I'm building a web app to do quoting for my workplace and most of it is working fine. I'm at a point where I need to take an object composed of a bunch of data from dynamically created user inputs and access it from the node server so that I can put that data into my mongodb database.

Through trolling through answers to similar questions I've been able to figure out that putting data into a hidden input I've named "quoteoutput" and then retrieving that using req.body.quoteoutput seems to be the way to go. As the submit function runs I do a console.log to check the variable actually has the stringified json object stored as a string, this shows up exactly as expected.

However when I get to the Node side of things the variable shows up as empty.

Hidden Input Declared in HTML:

```
<input type"hidden" name="quoteoutput" value="" />
```

Javascript to Change the Value to the stringified object:

```
outvalue = {customername: customer, quotelines: lines};
var output = document.getElementsByName("quoteoutput");
output.value = JSON.stringify(outvalue);
console.log("Output Value is:" + output.value);
```

The console in Chrome then displays exactly what is expected on the console.log

Post Request:

```
router.post('/addquote', function(req, res) {  
    var receivedobj = req.body.quoteoutput;
    console.log("Object is "  + receivedobj);
    res.send("OBJ Is " + receivedobj)
};
```

The next step would be to parse the string back into a JSON object so I can start compiling it to be put into the MongoDB Database appropriately but receivedobj is just showing up as blank, there is no string to parse back in. So that the output I get in the console.log here is:

"Object Is   "

And the res.send call brings up a blank page with:

"OBJ is"

And nothing else, apologies if this is a duplicate, I really tried searching for it somewhere else but couldn't find it.

Comment: hi, perhaps check the network trace in the browser's dev tools to see if it's beeing posted

Comment: are you using expressjs? have you set a body-parser?

Comment: @Bravo I am... and I have not, I assumed that would only be needed for the next step maybe that’s where I’m wrong I’ll try that now. Should be setting the body-parser in the main app.js file or the routers index.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Express does not read the body of the post.  You need some code that actually reads the body from the stream and then parses it based on its content-type. You don't show the whole client-side code to know exactly what content-type it is sending.  If it's a form, then it would be probably be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which you can read and parse with `express.urlencoded()` like this:

```
router.post('/addquote', express.urlencoded(), function(req, res) {  
    var receivedobj = req.body.quoteoutput;
    console.log("Object is "  + receivedobj);
    res.send("OBJ Is " + receivedobj)
});
```

Or you can generically install that middleware so it will work for all POST or PUT requests with that content-type:

```
router.use(express.urlencoded());

router.post('/addquote', function(req, res) {  
    var receivedobj = req.body.quoteoutput;
    console.log("Object is "  + receivedobj);
    res.send("OBJ Is " + receivedobj)
});
```

Or, at the app level, you can do:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Installing it as middleware will examine the incoming request.  If it's the type of request that has a body to it (like POST or PUT) and it has a matching content-type, then the middleware will read the rest of the incoming stream to get the body contents and then parse it according to its content type and then place the results into `req.body` for your actual request handler, further down the line to access.

---

It also looks like your client code might be a bit off because `document.getElementsByName()` returns a collection and you have to index that collection to access one particular object:

```
outvalue = {customername: customer, quotelines: lines};
var output = document.getElementsByName("quoteoutput")[0];   // see the [0] here
output.value = JSON.stringify(outvalue);
console.log("Output Value is:" + output.value);
```

This will set the actual `.value` property on the first DOM element with the "quoteoutput" name attribute.

Comment: Interestingly though, I did have it at the app level, for some reason it didn't work until I put it in the router level, then it worked fine...

Comment: @ConfusedCoder - Probably, your `app.use(yourRouter)` was BEFORE your `app.use(express.urlencoded())` so the router was running before the middleware had a chance to do its thing.